# Can someone find where's wrong in this code PHP email

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I'm not receiving mails on the email mail@example.com. Below is my form code and my send-mail.php code. Can anyone help me with this cause everything seems working great bu i'm not receiving any emails. I'm using localhost as the server.

Contact form:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post">
<p>Email us by filling in the form below. Make sure you fill in the message and all fields.</p>
<fieldset>
<div>
<input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your name" />
<label>Name</label>
</div>
<div>

<input name="web"  id="web" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your surname" />
                                     <label>Surname</label>
</div>
<div>
<input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
                                    <label>Email</label>
</div>

<div>
<textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- send mail configuration -->
<input type="hidden" value="mail@example.com" name="to" id="to" />
<input type="hidden" value="Enter the subject here" name="subject" id="subject" />
<input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
<!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

<p><input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
</fieldset>

</form>
<p id="sent-form-msg" class="success">Form data sent. Thanks for your feedback.</p>
<!-- ENDS form -->
```

and here is the send-mail.php

```
<?php
//vars
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

$from = $_POST['mail@example.com'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send for each mail
foreach($to as $mail){
mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you mind checking the return value of `mail` function to debug this?

Comment: Is mail configured on your localhost ? [Configure PHP Mail](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm)

Comment: Is it just me or does that "contact form" not match any of the $_POST things. Also I have no idea why a email address would be the name of one either.

Comment: place `if(mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers)) { echo "Success"; } else { echo "Sending mail Failed"; }` inside foreach loop.

Comment: i am sure you are not configured mail in local host.

Comment: Are you sending this with AJAX? Cause you currently dont have a PHP script specified, except in a hidden form element. I assume this is for javascript to read, but again we are missing code. Also, mail probably wont route to gmail from a local server without a domain, mx records, or reverse dns.

Comment: Also, input name='to' value='kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com' is not the same as $_POST['kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com']; it would be $_POST['to']

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['subject'];

$_POST['to'];

$_POST['myemail@gmail.com'];

$_POST['name'];

$_POST['email'];

$_POST['web'];

$_POST['comments'];
```

I didn’t find any of these elements in your form. That's the reason why nothing is happening.Try

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

This will give you the posted array when the form is submitted.

Comment: +1 your form looks like a login form, while your PHP looks like mail/comment submission. Maybe this was a mistake, either way, why are you trying to get your email address from the user? Shouldnt you hard code that in the script

Answer (score 0):

i have some suggestion.if u have kept the 'to' address as hidden in the form then why cant u try keeping it directly in sendmail function and in $from  you try to keep

```
<?php
$to="kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com";
$from =$_POST['field_name']; 
// not the mail id because i didn't see any field with name as "kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this function to send mail from localhost. I am not sure but you should try [PHP mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) for this task.